# mapstruct, Java and Spring Issues with target is not added

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapstruct

I do have one DTO Class and an Entity Class like this.

```
class ADTO {
....
....
   HashSet<BDTO> b; 
}

class AEntity {
.....
......
   HashSet<BEntity> b; 
}

class BDTO {
...
....
    
}

class BEntity {
.....
......
   AEntity a; 
}
```

I tried to use mapper with **uses**

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses=BMapper.class)
interface AMapper {
    
  ADTO toDTO(AEntity a);
   
  AEntity fromDTO(ADTO a);  
} 

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses=AMapper.class)
interface BMapper {
    
  BDTO toDTO(BEntity b);
   
  BEntity fromDTO(ADTO a, BDTO b); 

}
```

It is for "One to many" relations inside the "JPA entity". "DTO" is being used for JSON (Jackson parser).

```
ADTO toDTO(AEntity a);
```

The generator class is using Bmapper above method.

But

```
AEntity fromDTO(ADTO a);
```

is not using **Bmapper**. How can I force to use **Bmapper**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `@InheritInverseConfiguration`. It advises the code generator to apply all the Mappings from an inverse mapping method to the annotated method as well.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses=BMapper.class)
interface AMapper {
    
  ADTO toDTO(AEntity a);

  @InheritInverseConfiguration 
  AEntity fromDTO(ADTO a);  
}
```

Comment: BEntity has got a reference of AEntity. If "AMapper" uses BMapper "frpmDTO", I have define the mapping.

Comment: It hibernates one to many relationships between  AEntity and BEntity.

Comment: Have you tired the annotation and it's not working?

Comment: issue is with fromDTO